# best practice for django request.method methods

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm building a REST api and one of the methods from my view needs to accept the following http methods

```
GET
POST
DELETE
PUT
```

What is the best practice to achieve this ?

So far I came up with the following

```
with_id_storage = { 
'GET'   : _with_id_get,
'POST'  : _with_id_post,
'PUT'   : _with_id_put,
'DELETE': _with_id_delete,
}

def with_id(request, id):

try:
    log.info('calling %s' % request.method)
    return with_id_storage[request.method](request, test_id)
except KeyError:
    return HttpResponse('Not ready yet')
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Consider using **[django-piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home)**.  It does what you're asking for (and much more).